# Does Play Store register only manually submitted errors as Errors or all errors that occurred?

Tags: android, error-handling, google-play

When some app crashes, we have an option to Report this error.

So, does Play Store register **only such errors as Errors** or all errors which occur in some app gets registered as Errors regardless of a user reported them or not?

Look at the images to see which Errors I am referring to.

[image]

I cannot find any docs about this anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only if the user manually reports it.

And because of privacy issues this should be like this.